# wso2esb 403 on send to multiple endpoints changes message (deletes attributes in soap:Body)

Tags: soap, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

If i use send mediator with recipient list or clone mediator, wso2esb sends messages without attributes on soap:Body. I get signed message on proxy service, so it is critical to leave message as is.
Using send mediator with only one recipient (not in recipient list) works fine. On wso2esb version 481 everything works fine also.
I searched in wso2esb jira for closed bug, but didn't find anything usefull.

So, maybe somebody could provide some information about this problem or tell how i can circumvent the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the link to bugtracker: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1053

I finally made hook like this:

```
<!-- otherwise second request won't be sent -->
  <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
  <enrich>
     <source clone="false" type="envelope" xpath="" property="" />
     <target action="replace" type="property" xpath="" property="INIT_MSG" />
  </enrich>
  <clone sequential="false">
     <target>
        <sequence>
           <enrich>
              <source xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" clone="false" type="custom" xpath="get-property('INIT_MSG')" property="" />
              <target action="replace" type="envelope" xpath="" property="" />
           </enrich>
           <send>
              <endpoint>
                 <address uri="address1" />
              </endpoint>
           </send>
        </sequence>
     </target>
```